# iPhone: what is the search-list view controller called?

Tags: iphone

*I'm just beginning iPhone development, so please bear with me.*

I'm looking to make the first view of my application look like the search tab in the App Store, with a search box at the top and a list of results, and while the user is typing hopefully show the last-searched-for items.

Please point me in a good starting direction; is that a specific controller that I can just utilize, and if so, which one? Or where would I begin in creating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [`UISearchDisplayController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Really easy to implement.

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping it would be a prefab :) Thanks!